# What is the difference between GLMMs and MLMs

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmm

Generalized Linear Mixed Models (GLMMs) and Multilevel Models (MLMs) seem to sometimes be used in similar contexts.

1. What is the difference between the two.
2. Can both be used for hierarchical linear models (HLMs)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words "multilevel model" (MLM) and "hierarchical model" (HM) are interchangeable (see e.g. Gelman & Hill, 2006) and refer in general to a model with a hierarchy of stochastic processes, i.e. a model specification in which the result of a stochastic process enters into another stochastic process (= data distribution is a convolution of both processes).

A GLMM is a special case of this, where you have a normal GLM that has another stochastic process (the random effect) on the linear predictor.

I'm not sure that the term "hierarchical linear model" is used by everyone in the same way, but usually it refers to linear mixed models (LMM), so it's again a special example of a MLM, but not identical to a GLMM.

Gelman, A. & Hill, J. Data analysis using regression and multilevel/hierarchical models Cambridge University Press, 2006